# How to get dynamic value from URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, cordova

I am studying on AngularJS from there I want to load content from MySQL in reference with the URL value.

**The AngularJS RouteProvider I used is this:**

```
$routeProvider.when('/page/pages=:pages', {
     templateUrl: 'page.html',
     reloadOnSearch: false
});
```

My dynamic URL is:

```
"<a class='list-group-item' href='#/page/pages=" + slug + "'>" +
    title + " <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>" +
"</a>"
```

After that, I tried to alert the URL location on PhoneGap (screenshot attached)

[image]

Now, I want to pass this **pages** value to AJAX so I get a result query from MySQL.

```
$(function ()
{
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    jQuery.ajax({

        url: 'http://keralapsctuts.com/app/index.php', //the script to call to get data          
        data: "pages="+pages, //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
        type: "POST",   
        dataType: 'json',           //data format 
        success:function(data) {
            var result = "";
            var title = "";

            alert(pages);

            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var title = data[i]["pagetitle"];        //get name
                var content = data[i]["pagecontent"];        //get slug
                result += +content;
                title += "<span>"+title+"</span>";
            }

            $('#pcontent').html(content); //Set output element html
            $('#ptitle').html(title); //Set output element html
        }
    });
});
```

I am not getting any output.

Comment: are you calling same domain with the AJAX call? seems not. check you console for errors and post them if any appear

Comment: can you give suggestions. I don't see any error

Comment: answer my question, and i'll give you directions

Comment: yes, i am calling the same domain

Comment: you have only success handler as a first thing to do add an error handler too, to see if error happens. use `console.log` instead of `alert`, check your network tab in the developer tools if call is executed and whats the data call returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83999/discussion-between-kannan-and-reflective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab query parameters in your URL, use the AngularJS [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) provider.
If your url looks like example.com/#/page?pages=5, you can grab the value 5 by writing

```
 var urlPageValue = $location.search()["pages"];
```

Be sure to include the $location and $http services in your controller by writing

```
yourModuleName.controller("AwesomeController", ["$location", "$http", function($location, $http){
    // Page initialization code (like your ajax call) here
}])
```

Then, as Szanto suggested, use the $http service to do your ajax call by writing

```
$http({
    url:"/yourApiEndpoint",
    method: "POST",
    data: { pages: urlPageValue }
}).success(function(response){
    // Handle returned data here
}).error(function(){
    // Handle errors here
})
```

Finally, in your original question, when you got the data back from your SQL call, you were manually appending spans to the DOM. If you are going to use AngularJS, you should assign the response to an array variable and use the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive in your HTML to instantiate some template for each item in your array.

Comment: so i need to change 
`$routeProvider.when('/page/pages=:pages', {
     templateUrl: 'page.html',
     reloadOnSearch: false
});`

to 

`$routeProvider.when('/page?pages=:pages',   {templateUrl: 'page.html', reloadOnSearch: false});`

Comment: If you are trying to go to a route called "page", which has a variable called "pages" then yes. That is correct. Take for example a google search for "Stack Overflow", the url will look like https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow because there is some handler/route google is using called search which is looking for a search parameter named q with the value "Stack Overflow" in this case.

Comment: Starting from this fiddle I found at http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/NEuJ6/, I expanded it to include route parameters in the path as well as the query string. Using $routeParams, you can grab path variables as well as query string parameters. In this this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/amr4ez0v/5/, you can see what happens when you click links with path parameters and query parameters. In the controller we grab those parameters and display them, or use them in an ajax call.

Comment: Use the developer tools in Chrome to see if there are any javascript errors happening in the browser. In Chrome, right click and select "Inspect Element" and look for red errors in the console. Also, try setting a breakpoint in your server code to see that your templates are being fetched.

Comment: Read the error. AngularJS gives you a link to what the error is. It says "MainCtrl is not a function, got undefined." This is typically caused by not aliasing your controller in the html. In javascript, your controller should be called "MainController" and in your html, you would declare the controller as ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl". My guess is that you did not declare this properly.

Comment: Now its fixed, i see some small issues

Comment: I have another ptoblem HERE the JS `// Do an $http call to your site
  $http({
      url: "http://keralapsctuts.com/app/index.php",
      method: "POST",
      data:{
      param1: $scope.pageParameter,
      param2: $scope.queryParameter
      }
      }).success(function(response){
      $scope.pageid = response.pcontent;
  }).error(function(data) {
   $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
  });`

here

Comment: HERE the page.html `<div class="media-body">
         <p>Page Parameter: {{pageParameter}}</p>
    <p>Query Parameter: {{queryParameter}}</p>
          <p ng-repeat="pc in pageid">{{ pc.pagetitle }}</p>
          <pre>http status code: {{status}}</pre>
          <pre>http response data: {{data}}</pre>
        </div>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular and jQuery alongside? This is a bad idea, use Angular's built-in http [method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to replace the jQuery ajax request. Secondly, you can pass parameters to the request configuration (even in jQuery).

Comment: You can find an Angular example in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: $http.get(your_server,  {pages: pagesToLoad })
  .success(function (response) {$scope.pages = response.pages;});

Comment: I don't want to be rude or something, but if you google a little bit you can find excellent tutorials, examples and very good documentation. Sorry but I can't write the whole code for you (you are insisting from the beginning to write your code).

But I can explain a little bit: the last piece of code makes a GET request to the YOUR_SERVER url with the variable pagesToLoad, and if the request successfully sent and received puts the response sent back from the server in the $scope.pages variable.